# crash if deleting char* member in destructor of an imbricated own container using vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, dereference

till then i used to cope, here i'm trying to build my own container class using vector. I need it for my work. I'm using **codeblocks 10.05**

```
class myclass
{
    public :
      vector<myclass> array;
      char * classname;
      ...
```

The problem is that my datum of my class is **well displayed on screen if its deleting doesn't occur in the destructor.** My function show() diplays odd characters if I delete classname. I suppose it to come from my method to build object and a matter of range when I pass them as argument.

```
 myclass::~myclass()
 {
    //if(classname) delete [] classname;
 }
```

And this is how it is initialized in **the constructor :**

```
 myclass::myclass(long lvl = 0, const char name[] = "undefined")
    :ID(++ ID_counter)
    {
       level = lvl;

       int namelength = strlen(name);
       classname = new char[namelength + 1];
       strcpy(classname, name);
    }
```

**add_content(const myclass & c)** is supposed to make a copy of teh elements of c.array and "push_back" them in this->array
I find out per chance that we could put an object with no name as parameter : **mycontainer.add_content(myclass(3,5));**
it works but i'm skeptic about the scope it should have

```
> int main()
>     {
>        myclass mycontainer(0);
>        mycontainer.add_content(myclass(3,5));
>     ...
```

Here is **the full code :**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass
{
  public :

   vector<myclass> array;
   static long ID_counter;
   long ID;
   long level;
   char * classname;

   myclass(int n, long lvl, const char name[]); //push_back n elements, lvl = 0, name = "undefined"
   myclass(long lvl, const char name[]); //lvl = 0, name = "undefined"
   myclass::~myclass();

   void set_level(long lvl); //recursive function, go down the tree
   void add(int n); //push_back n elements
   void add(const myclass & c); //push_back and set back the levels
   void add_content(const myclass & c); //push_back all the c.array[i] and set back the levels

   void show();

   template <typename T> myclass & operator[](const T it){ return array[it]; }
};

long myclass::ID_counter = 0;

myclass::myclass(long lvl = 0, const char name[] = "undefined")
:ID(++ ID_counter)
{
   level = lvl;

   int namelength = strlen(name);
   classname = new char[namelength + 1];
   strcpy(classname, name);
}
myclass::myclass(int n, long lvl, const char name[] = "undefined")
:ID(++ ID_counter)
{
   level = lvl;

   int namelength = strlen(name);
   classname = new char[namelength + 1];
   strcpy(classname, name);

   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) array.push_back( myclass(this->level + 1) );
}
myclass::~myclass()
{
   //if(classname) delete [] classname; //there is the point !
}

void myclass::add(int n = 1)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) array.push_back( myclass(level + 1) );
}

void myclass::add(const myclass & c)
{
   array.push_back(c);
   array[array.size() - 1].set_level(level + 1);
}

void myclass::add_content(const myclass & c)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < c.array.size(); i++)
   {
      array.push_back(c.array[i]);
      array[array.size() - 1].set_level(level + 1);
   }
}

void myclass::set_level(long lvl)
{
   level = lvl;
   for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) array[i].set_level(level + 1);
}

void myclass::show()
{
   cout << "ID : " << ID << "\tLvl : " << level << "\t Classname : " << classname << endl;
}

int main()
{
   myclass mycontainer(0); //ground level
   mycontainer.add_content(myclass(3,5)); //the 3 elements level 5 should be reset to 0+1

   mycontainer.show();

   for(int i = 0; i < mycontainer.array.size(); i++)
   {
      mycontainer[i].show();

      for(int j= 0; j < mycontainer[i].array.size(); j++)
         mycontainer[i][j].show();
   }
   cout << "\ncheckpoint\n";
   system("PAUSE"); //press any key to crash!
   return 0;
}
```

here **no deletion of *classname in the destructor**, the program rend this :

```
ID : 1  Lvl : 0  Classname : undefined
ID : 3  Lvl : 1  Classname : undefined
ID : 4  Lvl : 1  Classname : undefined
ID : 5  Lvl : 1  Classname : undefined

checkpoint
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

**with deletion** and some bad characters show up with a crash:

```
ID : 1  Lvl : 0  Classname : undefined
ID : 3  Lvl : 1  Classname : ░(?
ID : 4  Lvl : 1  Classname : ░(?
ID : 5  Lvl : 1  Classname : ░(?

checkpoint
Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 29.651 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I tried to study back some principles about arguments and pointers but this language is too empirical and makes no sense. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Perhaps a review of [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) may shed light on this, specifically for `myclass` (if that wasn't obvious).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a raw pointer and didn't define a copy constructor or assignment operator. That means you're getting the automatically generated versions, something you don't want. Review the Rule of Three.

Solution #1: Implement a proper copy constructor and assignment operator.

Solution #2: Change `char * classname` to `std::string classname`. Now the automatically generated copy constructor and assignment operator will work. Added benefit: You don't need to use `new`, you don't need to use `delete`.

Comment: +1 I opt for Solution #2, as well as making at least one of those constructors protected or private.

Answer (score 1):

You should define copy constructor.

My debugger raises error here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) array.push_back( myclass(this->level + 1) );
```

we see here, that new object of `myclass` is created, then copied (cloned) into `array`, then original is destroyed as any local variable does.

So, we have two instances with the same pointer: one destroyed, another inside `array`, created by default copy constructor which copies just raw memory. So, instance inside `array` is invalid, since destructor was already ran on it.

**THE CODE**

The following additional constructor will solve the situation:

```
myclass::myclass(const myclass& other) 
:ID(++ ID_counter) 
{
   level = other.level;

   int namelength = strlen(other.classname);
   classname = new char[namelength + 1];
   strcpy(classname, other.classname);
}
```

(above is what is called "copy constructor"; yes, of course you should obey "rule of three" to avoid all potential bugs)